# How to get url of video element of an iframe using php

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

Good afternoon friend,

I am trying to be able to take the video from the url of the iframe, from what I see I have to first click the video so that the video element is visible in html.

Isn't there a way to automate the process? Click automatically when entering the url and extract the url from the video

The url is: https://feurl.com/v/2625zf2pddy2ge

I'm supposed to get the following url from the video at the end.

`https://fvs.io/redirector?token=aVVHRmZNVzZVdldkRXJUZXdrSWRQV2RxQ2RSSjdFNGphTVBVQTVBRTR4TlpFYXdMbzlXaktueW9ETW5ma2QvYjlOZG42Mzg2eGNWSDNjT3BHUC8wMmxyUTcrZyt4ZzRwV0s4UWVLcWQzZExzdUVBN1dIbUVmSVhrbnlIWENwWHhFR09LRVBHcXpLUmg4NFlCaW10SzBGeVU2VXVNL3FvMjpUMXRDKytHYng5S1RTTU1laG0vbFZRPT0`

My code is:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('https://feurl.com/v/2625zf2pddy2ge');


preg_match('/<video[^>]*src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $data, $matches);
$video = $matches[1];

echo $video;
?>
```

Comment: Try web scraping libraries in php

Comment: i tried and not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both links dont work but assuming html looks something like this `a.html`:

```
<video width="320" height="240" src="https://fvs.io/redirector?token=aVVHRmZNVzZVdldkRXJUZXdrSWRQV2RxQ2RSSjdFNGphTVBVQTVBRTR4TlpFYXdMbzlXaktueW9ETW5ma2QvYjlOZG42Mzg2eGNWSDNjT3BHUC8wMmxyUTcrZyt4ZzRwV0s4UWVLcWQzZExzdUVBN1dIbUVmSVhrbnlIWENwWHhFR09LRVBHcXpLUmg4NFlCaW10SzBGeVU2VXVNL3FvMjpUMXRDKytHYng5S1RTTU1laG0vbFZRPT0"></video>
```

Try this:

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('a.html');


preg_match('/<video.*?src="(.*?)"/', $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
string(279) "https://fvs.io/redirector?token=aVVHRmZNVzZVdldkRXJUZXdrSWRQV2RxQ2RSSjdFNGphTVBVQTVBRTR4TlpFYXdMbzlXaktueW9ETW5ma2QvYjlOZG42Mzg2eGNWSDNjT3BHUC8wMmxyUTcrZyt4ZzRwV0s4UWVLcWQzZExzdUVBN1dIbUVmSVhrbnlIWENwWHhFR09LRVBHcXpLUmg4NFlCaW10SzBGeVU2VXVNL3FvMjpUMXRDKytHYng5S1RTTU1laG0vbFZRPT0"
```

If it doesnt work dump your $data and make sure the video tag is even there. Sometimes this is loaded later via ajax, so it is not even available in initial response.

Comment: Ok i'm trying for this link but it doesn't work: https://jetload.net/e/1QM5dOaBsQcY

Comment: See last paragraph of my answer. Did you check contents of $data? For url you provided this is what you will find there: `<video id="video"  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" controls playsinline  >`. Video tag has no src attribute. It is added later via client side code (js) probably. You would have to figure out how it is constructed or even have to run this js code to obtain it. Not a trivial task and different for different pages.

Comment: file_get_contents does not extract the video tag and that makes the code not work. Is there a way to get the html without that function